# Comparison of highly nonlinear parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $[0,T]$ be the time domain, and $I:=(-\pi,\pi)$ be the space domain.

Consider a parabolic (4th order, nonlinear) PDE
$$u_t=-A(u_x,u_{xx},u_{xxx})-B(u_x,u_{xx},u_{xxx},u_{xxxx}),\quad u:[0,T]\longrightarrow W^{1,q}(I), q\in (1,+\infty).$$ 
Here $A$ is linear, but not $B$.

We know that:

1. solutions of
   $$v_t= -B(u_x,u_{xx},u_{xxx},u_{xxxx})$$
   are $e^T$-Lipschitz with respect to $t$.
2. there exists $c$ such that for almost every time $t$ it holds
   $$\|A(u_x,u_{xx},u_{xxx})\| \leq c\|u_{xxx}\|,$$
   where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the operator norm of $W^{-1,q^*}(I)$, with $1/q+1/q^*=1$.

We know no a priori regularity on $u_t$. Is it possible to compare solutions
of 
$$u_t=-A(u_x,u_{xx},u_{xxx})-B(u_x,u_{xx},u_{xxx},u_{xxxx})$$
with solutions of $v_t= -B(u_x,u_{xx},u_{xxx},u_{xxxx})$ and $w_t=-w_{xxx}$ to get some regularity for $u_t$?

Thank you.

Comment: is there any boundary condition we know?

Comment: Boundary conditions are periodicity of 1st and 2nd derivatives in space, and $u(0)=u^0$, a given initial datum.